# OAS date filter expression

Tags: oracle, oas

I want limit data by day of last date in table(not sysdate), but all I try is not successful.
With SQL it can be achieved as

```
SELECT * FROM INFO WHERE TRUNC (CHECK_TIME) = (SELECT MAX (TRUNC (CHECK_TIME)) FROM INFO)
```

at filter expression I wrote something like this

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_DAY, ExtractDay(CHECK_TIME), (ExtractDay(MAX(CHECK_TIME))))=0
```

but filter doesn`t work as I think.
Could somebody help please?

Comment: Where are you writing that filter expression exactly?

Comment: @Chris,  visualisation -> grammar pane - > filter -> Add expression filter. I also try "Relative filter" but they has only one option "relative to today" which is not what I want.